# powershell runspace failed to open after MVC controller inheriting from BaseController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, model-view-controller, routes

In my mvc web Bilingual application, I have a controller (ProductController ) connects exchange server through powershell command to get data from the exchange server, it works fine if the ProductController inherit from Controller, but it failed if the ProductController inherits from BaseController, 
In debug mode, I got this error message on runspace.Open()

```
 Connecting to remote server xxxxxx.ca failed with the  
 following error message : 
<f:WSManFault 
xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault"  
   Code="3762507597" Machine="xxxxxx.CA">
<f:Message><f:ProviderFault provider="PowerShellplugin" path="%windir%\system32\pwrshplugin.dll">
    </f:ProviderFault>
</f:Message>
```

For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help  enter code here

this is the code of ProductController

```
public class ProductController : BaseController 
PSCredential newCred;
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo;
        Runspace runspace;
        PowerShell powershell;
        PSCommand command;
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject> psresult3 = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject>();        
        string sResult = "";       
        string sUser = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ProdUser").ToString();
        string sPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ProdPassword").ToString();
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();         
        foreach (char c in sPassword.ToCharArray())
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        newCred = new PSCredential(sUser, securePassword);
        connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WSManConnectionInfo").ToString()), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", newCred);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
        try
        {            
            runspace.Open();  //error message happens here when the controller inherits from BaseController
            powershell = PowerShell.Create();
           enter code here
```

this is the codes of BaseController

```
   [Localization("en")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
   private string CurrentLanguageCode { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] != null && requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] as string != "null")
        {
            CurrentLanguageCode = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"];
            if (CurrentLanguageCode != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(CurrentLanguageCode);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid language code '{CurrentLanguageCode}'.");
                }
            }
        }
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
} enter code here
```